# Change screen unlock method (old Symbian style) on KitKat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung, lock-screens

Ever since I switched from Symbian to Android I missed a feature that I consider to be of extreme handiness.

On my old Nokias, I had a short timer (like 10 seconds) that locked the screen in a simple way (the standard two-key combination) and then a longer timer (like 15 minutes) that locked the phone with my personal code. The two-key combination was very fast and also unlikely to happen by accident.

Now I'm running Android 4.4.2 on a Samsung SM-C101 and I have this problem: the "simple" lock method is pressing either the home key or the power key, which is bound to happen when I put the phone in my pocket.

I would like to "swipe to unlock" every time the screen goes off, and to "enter a code" if the screen stays off for some minutes.

But that's not an option on Android 4.4.2 , you only get one unlock method.

I don't want to perform a complicated unlock action every time I put my phone in and out of my pocket and I don't want to leave it unprotected in case it gets stolen.

I can't find an app that replicates the Symbian lock properly. I tried some but they behaved poorly. Do you know some app that does what I want? My phone is rooted.

Since the phone is rooted, is there a way to change the standard behavior of the power and home key? Like, press them in sequence to turn the screen on, or at least disable one of the two (I guess the Home key is more likely to be pressed when the phone is inside a pocket).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible solution for this, but it requires root:

The app "Sequence Unlock" can wake up the screen with a combination of volume up&down and (this is optional) disable the power&home button (only both together unfortunately)

It requires the Xposed Framework